# how can store data of table from website using DataFrame to csv file #Python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd
import requests #not always required but needed for some sites so doing it this way

url = 'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunis'

page = requests.get(url)
table = pd.read_html(page.text)
df = table[3]

print(df)

df.to_csv('Climate_data_for_Dubai.csv', index=False)


                                  Mois  jan.  fév.  mars  avril  mai  juin  jui.  août  sep.  oct.  nov.  déc.  année
0    Température minimale moyenne (°C)    72    74    83    104  137   173    20   208    19   155   113    82     13
1    Température maximale moyenne (°C)   157   165   181    207  249    29   326   327   297   252   205   167     23
2                   Ensoleillement (h)   146   160   198    225  282   309   357   329   258   217   174   149  2 804
3                  Précipitations (mm)    59    57    47     38   23    10     2     7    36    66    54    63    462
4  Nombre de jours avec précipitations    12    12    11      9    5     3     1     2     6     9    10    12     92
```

> I don't know why it doesn't create a CSV file and store the data
> inside it. please help me..

Comment: please check it will be in your working directory where you execute above code also you can specify path for csv too.

Comment: This works for me: it writes a file to my working directory. Try the suggestion above.

Comment: @BhavyaParikh It really works. Thank you, dude, for the information. You can't imagine how tired I am looking for a solution to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten your code to the following using `pd.read_html`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunis')[3]
df.to_csv('Climate_data_for_Dubai.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: thanks dude ...
Can I extract a name of table and there class name using the read_html(url) ?

Comment: @sakomalten No. You mean the HTML code around the table? No.  I don't think so.